# Struggling to decode JSON in jquery ajax success callback from PHP script

Tags: php, json, jquery

I've been trying to find an answer for this for hours but really struggling.

I have a simple jquery Ajax function which sends data to a PHP script. The data is then used to conduct a MySQL query and the results are included as an array. I'm sending the array back using `json_encode` but can't work out how to display the array at the other end. I've posted the code below. The `console.log` is displaying `Object {modules: Array[0]}`
. There should be 3 entries in the array.

**The PHP**

```
<?php
 include_once('../../dbconnect.php');

$name = $_POST['uploadname'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM marking_assignments WHERE name = '$name'";
$details = $conn->query($query);
$modules = array();

while ($row = $details->fetch_assoc()){
 $modules[] = $row['unit'];
}

$dataarray = array("modules"=>$modules);
 echo json_encode($dataarray);
?>
```

**The jQuery**

```
  var uploadname;

  $("#uploadname").blur(function(){
   uploadname = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
            url: "uploadnames.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {uploadname: uploadname},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
             }
            });

         });
```

Comment: You're certain everything on the php side is in order, such as $row['unit'] and all of that?

Comment: Might have something to do with the echo json_encode($modules); in the while loop. Looks like that shouldn't really be there?

Comment: If you're returning json to jQuery, you should only have one echo on the page. I'm surprised you're not getting a parseerror

Comment: Oops, hadn't noticed that - I've changed it now but doesn't seem to have resolved the problem

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: I know about SQL injections, I just choose not to escape the variables when posting on SO to make it easier to read

Comment: If the output is `Object {modules: Array[0]} `, then it looks you don't have a problem with parsing the data but with creating the right data. What do you see in the browser when you open the URL directly (switch to `GET` for that purpose) or in the network tab of the developer tools? Do you get the expected data?

Answer (score 1):

you should use:

```
  var parsedData =  jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

and then:

```
  console.log(parsedData)
```

Comment: No, jQuery will parse the JSON automatically in this case. The console wouldn't show `Object {modules: Array[0]} ` if it wasn't parsed.